# Tooltip not showing left of first element when first element selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my code below is an example of what I've got so far. I'm using `$('.recommended_slot:first')` to find the element to append my tooltip to, however when it's appended it shows next to the next element down from the first recommended slot.

If anybody as any suggestions on how to do this better or why it's messing up.  Then it would be great to hear any advise. Thanks :)

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Larocw9v/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 addPopOverEvery(2, '.slot:not(.alreadyBooked)');
   findBestRecommendedSlot();
});

function addPopOverEvery(n, selector) {
 $(selector).each(function() {
  var $original = $(this),
  $self = $(this),
  $is_pop = true,
  i = 0;
  if ($original.prev().is(selector)) {
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    $self = $self.prev();
    if (!$self.is(selector) || $self.find('.popOver').length) {
     $is_pop = false;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($is_pop) {
   $self = $original;
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    $self = $self.next();
    if (!$self.is(selector)) {
     $is_pop = false;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($is_pop) {
   $original.addClass("recommended_slot");
   $original.css("color", "red");
  }
 });
}

function findBestRecommendedSlot(){
  $('.recommended_slot:first').text('recommended');
  $('.recommended_slot:first').append('<span class="tooltiptext">This slot is recommended</span>');
  
  
}
```

```css
.popOver{
   width:400px;
   height: 30px;
   background: green;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 999;
   margin-left: 120px;
   opacity: 0.5;
   color: white!important;
}

.tooltiptext {
 width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin-right: 330px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -112px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="slot">15:10 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:15 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot alreadyBooked">15:20 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot alreadyBooked">15:25 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:30 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:35 18/08/2016</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For me the tooltip is rendering after the first list item: http://b.ntrn.cc/2j313X2P2o2V. Do you just need the CSS changed to reposition the tooltip element?

Comment: Could you make a fiddle?

Comment: @bbodien Check updated JSFiddle example

Comment: @GeoffJames check JSFiddle example

Comment: it's in the first `<li>` ..you just need to adjust style. Inspect the live html in your browser dev tools

Comment: I think @Goombah's answer below is what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually placed right, only your CSS messes it up.. ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 addPopOverEvery(2, '.slot:not(.alreadyBooked)');
   findBestRecommendedSlot();
});

function addPopOverEvery(n, selector) {
 $(selector).each(function() {
  var $original = $(this),
  $self = $(this),
  $is_pop = true,
  i = 0;
  if ($original.prev().is(selector)) {
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    $self = $self.prev();
    if (!$self.is(selector) || $self.find('.popOver').length) {
     $is_pop = false;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($is_pop) {
   $self = $original;
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    $self = $self.next();
    if (!$self.is(selector)) {
     $is_pop = false;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($is_pop) {
   $original.addClass("recommended_slot");
   $original.css("color", "red");
  }
 });
}

function findBestRecommendedSlot(){
  $('.recommended_slot:first').text('recommended');
  $('.recommended_slot:first').append('<span class="tooltiptext">This slot is recommended</span>');
  
  
}
```

```css
.popOver{
   width:400px;
   height: 30px;
   background: green;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 999;
   margin-left: 120px;
   opacity: 0.5;
   color: white!important;
}

.tooltiptext {
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -115px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="slot">15:10 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:15 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot alreadyBooked">15:20 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot alreadyBooked">15:25 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:30 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:35 18/08/2016</li>
</ul>
```

Here's one especially for Charlie! Kisses!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 addPopOverEvery(2, '.slot:not(.alreadyBooked)');
   findBestRecommendedSlot();
});

function addPopOverEvery(n, selector) {
 $(selector).each(function() {
  var $original = $(this),
  $self = $(this),
  $is_pop = true,
  i = 0;
  if ($original.prev().is(selector)) {
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    $self = $self.prev();
    if (!$self.is(selector) || $self.find('.popOver').length) {
     $is_pop = false;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($is_pop) {
   $self = $original;
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    $self = $self.next();
    if (!$self.is(selector)) {
     $is_pop = false;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($is_pop) {
   $original.addClass("recommended_slot");
   $original.css("color", "red");
  }
 });
}

function findBestRecommendedSlot(){
  $('.recommended_slot:first').text('recommended');
  $('.recommended_slot:first').append('<span class="tooltiptext">This slot is recommended</span>');
  
  
}
```

```css
.popOver{
   width:400px;
   height: 30px;
   background: green;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 999;
   margin-left: 120px;
   opacity: 0.5;
   color: white!important;
}

.tooltiptext {
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -13px;
}

.tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -115px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="slot">15:10 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:15 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot alreadyBooked">15:20 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot alreadyBooked">15:25 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:30 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:35 18/08/2016</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: doesn't look a whole lot better since it distorts parent size

Comment: That's OP's choice. They chose to make the tooltip 120px wide.That forces the text to break into two lines. Element could be made absolute to prevent that but that's beside the question.

Comment: huh? can easily resolve using css or put it elsewhere. OP is asking how to fix it, how can it be their fault

Comment: Yes, it can, but once again, that wasn't the (original) question. That wasn't what needed fixing as stated in the question. Tooltips wasn't next to recommened, now it is.

Comment: Sure it is. They asked how to get it beside it. Doubt they expect a solution that distorts the elements.

Comment: @Goombah thanks, this was what i was looking for. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

One more idea

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 addPopOverEvery(2, '.slot:not(.alreadyBooked)');
   findBestRecommendedSlot();
});

function addPopOverEvery(n, selector) {
 $(selector).each(function() {
  var $original = $(this),
  $self = $(this),
  $is_pop = true,
  i = 0;
  if ($original.prev().is(selector)) {
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    $self = $self.prev();
    if (!$self.is(selector) || $self.find('.popOver').length) {
     $is_pop = false;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($is_pop) {
   $self = $original;
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    $self = $self.next();
    if (!$self.is(selector)) {
     $is_pop = false;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($is_pop) {
   $original.addClass("recommended_slot");
   $original.css("color", "red");
  }
 });
}

function findBestRecommendedSlot(){
  $('.recommended_slot:first').text('recommended');
  $('.recommended_slot:first').append('<span class="tooltiptext">This slot is recommended</span>');
  
  
}
```

```css
.popOver{
   width:400px;
   height: 30px;
   background: green;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 999;
   margin-left: 120px;
   opacity: 0.5;
   color: white!important;
}

.tooltiptext {
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
}

.tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -115px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="slot">15:10 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:15 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot alreadyBooked">15:20 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot alreadyBooked">15:25 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:30 18/08/2016</li>
  <li class="slot">15:35 18/08/2016</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is prettier, added similar example to my answer as well.